# Hangfire.Console Error with .NET Framework

Tags: c#, webforms, hangfire, hangfire-console

I use hangfire in a webforms project. Hangfire itself was working. Then I installed `Hangfire.Console` extension to add log messages, but now I get an error

> Error CS0234
> The type or namespace name 'Console' does not exist in the namespace 'Hangfire' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  HangTest2

My code:

Packages:

[image]

Global:

[image]

Startup:

[image]

As you have noted there is no usecosole - what am I doing wrong?

I'm using .NET Framework 4.7 and an ASP.NET webforms project

Edit

auto complete working with hangfire.console
[image]

Edit : the link is talking about Hangfire with log packages
My Question about the package Hangfire.Console

Comment: In your startup, use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseConsole();` right after your `UseSqlServerStorage()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this.

```
.UseSqlServerStorage("connectionSting")
    .UseConsole();
```

`Hangfire.Console` provides extension methods on PerformContext object, hence you'll need to add it as a job argument.
NOTE: Like `IJobCancellationToken`, `PerformContext` is a special argument type which Hangfire will substitute automatically. You should pass `null` when enqueuing a job.
Now you can write to console:

```
public void TaskMethod(PerformContext context)
{
    context.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
}
```

**Reference**: https://github.com/pieceofsummer/Hangfire.Console

Comment: as i mentioned above i do not have .useconsole() please see image